# Graph of $f(x) = (-e)^x$

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions

> What would the graph of $f(x) = (-e)^x$ look like? If a graph is not possible, why not?

Trying to visualise this function seems difficult as a small change in x can change the sign of f(x) but I am not sure what the formal reason as to why this function cannot be graphed. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is $\sqrt{-e}$? (that would be $f(1/2)$)

Comment: Well when $x=\frac1{2k}$ for any positive $k\in\mathbb{N}$ you can't plot it on a graph in the real domain...

Comment: Raising negative numbers to arbitrary real powers requires thinking about complex numbers and turns out to be pretty subtle. Think about $(-1)^{1/2}$. There are many discussions of this point on this site.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite $(-e)^x$ as $(-1)^xe^x$. The real problem is with $(-1)^x$. In some sense, the "right way" to interpret that is by writing $-1=e^{\pi i}$, so its values all lie around the unit circle in the complex plane.

Multiplying a rotating term $(-1)^x$, by a growth term $e^x$, we obtain a spiral in the complex plane. It only intersects the real line when $x$ is an integer, so if you're trying to graph it in the way that we usually graph real functions, you'll end up with points at integer $x$ values, and a graph that you can't see everywhere else.

Once you study complex variables, it's not too hard to make sense of, but there are considerations that we don't have to deal with when we look at exponential functions with positive real bases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I can intuitively visualise the function now. However you state that f(x) only intersects the real axis when x is an integer but what about a value of x such as 1/3 or 3/5? The cube root of a negative number has a real solution and f(3/4) can be evaluated as (((-e)^3)^1/5) which has a real solution. Do we not represent all evaluations of an x value on the graph?

Comment: @nedia , That's one of those considerations that we don't have to deal with in exponentials of a positive real base. There are three different cube roots of $-1$, namely $-1$ and $\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}{2} i$. If we take $-1$ to be $e^{\pi i}$, then it makes sense to use $\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$ as its principal cube root. Alternatively, we can take $-1$ to be $e^{3\pi i}$, and then we would choose $-1$ as its cube root. In either case, it's just a matter of dividing that exponent by $3$.